# Working with dates in VBA that are strings

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of files that follow the following naming scheme:SOP_Audit-JV-006-02182019.docx

The last part of the file name is a date that I want to pull into VBA, which I have working fine using Split(). Is there something similar to this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php in VBA? Something that would allow me to convert that string to a date and then be able to format it differently, or compare it with another date, break it down into just the month or year, etc.

I was reading about the CDate function and trying to use that but am having some issues with it.

Thank you!

Comment: Try creating a `Date` variable and using `TimeSerial` with `Year(myString)`, `Month(myString)`, and `Day(myString)` - might work for you.

Comment: Something like this? https://software-solutions-online.com/excel-vba-working-with-dates/#Jump1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `DateSerial` with some right, mid and left combination:

```
DateSerial(Right("02182019", 4), Left("02182019", 2), Mid("02182019", 3, 2))
```

Comment: That did it! Dim auditDate: auditDate = CDate(DateSerial(Right(Left(Split(oFile.Name, "-")(3), 8), 4), _
                                                        Left(Left(Split(oFile.Name, "-")(3), 8), 2), _
                                                        Mid(Left(Split(oFile.Name, "-")(3), 8), 3, 2)))

Answer (score 3):

While your question has already been answered, let me add a piece of advice: when using a date in string format, especially for file names, it pays off to use YYYYMMDD (*with or w/o separators*) as the date's format. Doing it that way, sorting the strings ascending/descending automatically creates also the correct chronological order. [See ISO 8601 (date format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).